# Jenkins перестал возвращать ошибки при запуске тестов

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Всем привет!
Уже задавал этот вопрос на одном форуме, но не получил ответа. Продублирую тут со всеми результатами.
Суть вопроса:
Есть jenkins, который крутит тесты (python + wd). В самом теле скрипта есть ф-я на выгрузку отчетов HTMLTestRunner.
 
Jenkins не показывает **Finished: SUCCESS** , не смотря на то что сам тест упал. Происходит это потому что *C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Џа®ўҐаЄ ­ «ЁзЁп ¬®¤ «м­ле ®Є®­\workspace>* **exit 0** .
Подозреваю, что такой поведение может быть вызвано тем, что последняя ф-я  это как раз HTMLTestRunner, и он постоянно в не зависимости от результатов ф-ий выше пишет отчет успешно, вот и jenkins ему верит и не падает. 
Подскажите, как от этого избавиться?
Прикладываю код:

```
class ASeleniumLogin_1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_001_LoginInSYSDev(self):
        assert "Login" in driver.title
        _ = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'LoginForm_username')))
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("LoginForm_username1")     # НИКОГДА НЕ НАЙДЕТ ЭТОТ ЭЛЕМЕНТ, СДЕЛАНО ДЛЯ ВЫЗОВА ОШИБКИ
        elem.send_keys("user")
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("LoginForm_password")
        elem.send_keys("pass")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        print('\n 1. Логинимся в систему')
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'hidden-xs')))
if __name__ == '__main__':
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(ASeleniumLogin_1))
        buf = open("at_for_MATERIAL.html", 'wb')
        runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
        stream=buf,
        title='Отчет по тестированию',
        description='Отчет по тестированию'
        )
 runner.run(suite)
```

[image: Скрин части джоба]

Так же нашел такую тему: [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972636/jenkins-always-considers-a-build-successful-using-batch-bat)

В ней человек встретился с похоже проблемой. Задам глупый вопрос, если то, что там описано, действительно справедливо в моем случае, то где использовать EXIT XX В самой команде на сборку в jenkins или в коде скрипта?
Заранее благодарю за ответ(ы)

Comment: `Jenkins не показывает Finished: SUCCESS , не смотря на то что сам тест упал\\` может, наоборот,  показывает?

Comment: EXIT XX нужно в коде использовать. 

пробуй еще отключить HTMLTestRunner, прогнать прогон и посмотреть  на результат

Comment: Сейчас прогоняю такую конструкцию:  `import sys .. if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(ASeleniumLogin_1))
    # File
    buf = open("at_for_QUESTIONS_AND_PRIORITY.html", 'wb')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
        stream=buf,
        title='СОЗДАНИЕ И УДАЛЕНИЕ ПРИОРИТЕТА',
        description='Отчет по тестированию'
    )
    ret = not runner.run(suite).wasSuccessful()
    sys.exit(ret)`  вроде, заработало, но надо ещё потестировать

Comment: `Џа®ўҐаЄ ­ «ЁзЁп ¬®¤ «м­ле ®Є®­\` намекает на проблемы с кодировкой )

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins запускает все shell-скрипты в режиме `-x` (отладка) и `-e` (завершать работу при первой ошибке). Если любой тест вернул FAILURE, с точки зрения скрипта это ошибка, поэтому завершается выполнение скрепта и следом фейлится весь запуск.

Решается так.

```
# в самом начале скрипта:
set +e
... 
# дальше запуск тестов
...

exit 0
# конец скрипта
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую и этот вариант, но помог предыдущий:    
    `ret = not runner.run(suite).wasSuccessful()
    sys.exit(ret)`